# How I can authenticate to an API with curl --digest

Tags: android, image-recognition

I use moodstocks to recognise image, 
I just want now how I can convert this code:

```
curl --digest -u YourApiKey:YourApiSecret \
"http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/echo/?foo=bar&bacon=chunky"
```

To Android

https://moodstocks.com/docs/http-api/how-to-use-the-api/#adding-or-removing-reference-images

I can do that with Python or PHP, but I didn't find any code wit Android

```
import moodstocks
C = moodstocks.APIClient("YourApiKey", "YourApiSecret")
```

Thanks advice

Answer (score 0):

did you try the official documentation??

https://moodstocks.com/docs/android/getting-started-large-image-database/

it seems all nicely explained.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.moodstocks.android.Scanner;
import com.moodstocks.android.MoodstocksError;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // Moodstocks API key/secret pair
  private static final String API_KEY    = "your_api_key";
  private static final String API_SECRET = "your_api_secret";

  private boolean compatible = false;
  private Scanner scanner;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    compatible = Scanner.isCompatible();
    if (compatible) {
      try {
        scanner = Scanner.get();
        String path = Scanner.pathFromFilesDir(this, "scanner.db");
        scanner.open(path, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
      } catch (MoodstocksError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (compatible) {
      try {
        scanner.close();
        scanner.destroy();
        scanner = null;
      } catch (MoodstocksError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did , i want know how i can convert curl --digest to Android , for example  how i can send the image to server Moodstocks : curl --digest -u YourApiKey:YourApiSecret "http://api.moodstocks.com/v2/ref/YourID" --form image_file=@"test-updated.jpg" -X PUT

Comment: You can use some weird dirty demo ports of curl `https://github.com/liudongmiao/curl-android` which is likely to not work very well. Or you accept that is a different system and use what the different system and the official documentation suggest you.